# Why can't we have the equality in Clifford's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying this [article](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416) and in the second page of the second chapter I didn't understand why we can have a strict sign $\lt$ instead of less equal sign $\le$ in Clifford's theorem.

[image]

We know that the Clifford's Theorem is stated in this way:

> If $l(D)\gt 0$, and $l(W-D)\gt 0$, then $l(D)\le\frac{1}{2}\deg(D)+1$

**Remark**: My only background is [Fulton's Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) book.

I really help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clifford's theorem also tells you the cases where equality happens. These are the cases where $C$ is hyperelliptic, $D$ is canonical or $D$ is trivial. In the paper $C$ is assumed to be non-hyperelliptic and by definition of $E$, it is strictly less than a canonical divisor. So the only non-excluded case is that $E=0$, which is incorporated in the statement of the proposition.